# expression tag not assigning value of a string to innerHTML

Tags: html, jsp

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <%! String S="Name"; %>
  <label id="foo"> </label>

  <script type="text/javascript">

   document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML=<%=S%>;
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the innerHTML of the label foo does not change.Can comebody explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap string within quotes in Javascript otherwise it may throw some syntax error.

```
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML= "<%=S%>";
```